# iOS corrupts TLS data sent to server

Tags: ios, websocket, ssl

I have the same problem using either the SocketRocket or Unitt web socket libraries on iOS to perform secure web sockets. I have control over the Java web socket server - Netty - and can observe the server-side SSL/TLS data in detail. I use port 6970 for the socket.

After the client wss socket is properly opened with a TLS handshake, I get a server error on the first client data write, i.e. the web socket handshake. The client writes 202 bytes, the server receives 272 bytes and the message authentication code fails on the server. I see my client data in the server trace, but it has 8 bytes of garbage pre-pended.

First I tried the SocketRocket library with the same results on the server - bad MAC after a good handshake. My android version of the Unitt client works great. My JavaScript secure web socket code also works great.

On iOS / XCode I can debug as far as CFWriteStreamWrite(...) in Unitt/AsyncSocket/doSendBytes - which reports that 202 client data bytes indeed get written. But I am at a loss as to how to debug further. Somewhere, the iOS TLS framework is corrupting my client data during the send - I think.

Comment: Are you sure it's not getting corrupted over the wire somehow?

Comment: No. But that is easy to check. I will install the Charles proxy on my development Mac to intercept the TCP packets. I expect to see the same error reported by Charles because it is written in Java and uses sort of code that my server app does.

Comment: The Charles proxy did not work for my port 6970, so I installed Wireshark and observed that although my application wrote 202 bytes, the local network interface transmitted 277 bytes. I do not see where I can obtain the debug libraries for my Mac OS version 10.7.3.

Comment: Supposing that there is indeed a Mac OS library error, I am going to try using port 443 rather than 6970 for wss://, and if that does not work I will try port 80 for ws://. The trouble is that I must run my server app as root or use iptables in order to use ports 80 or 443 - and that will take some work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my iOS secure web socket running with my Java Netty server by filtering out certain elipical curve cipher suites that were not compatible with iOS. Here is my code ...

```
/** the enabled SSL cipher suites */
private static String[] enabledCipherSuites;
/** the enabled SSL cipher suites lock */
private static final Object ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES_LOCK = new Object();
/** the iOS incompatible cipher suites */
private static final List<String> iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites = new ArrayList<>();

/** Configures the SSL engine for client or for the server. Arranges the enabled ciphers to favor the
* most secure over the less secure, and omits the least secure ciphers.  Requires that the SSL server
* authenticate the client.
*
* @param sslEngine the SSL engine
* @param useClientMode the indicator whether the SSL engine is operating in client mode
* @param needClientAuth the indicator whether the server authenticates the client's SSL certificate
*/
public static synchronized void configureSSLEngine(
         final SSLEngine sslEngine,
         final boolean useClientMode,
         final boolean needClientAuth) {
  //Preconditions
  assert sslEngine != null : "sslEngine must not be null";

  if (useClientMode) {
    LOGGER.info("configuring SSL engine for the client side of the connection");
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true);
    sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(false);
  } else {
    if (needClientAuth) {
      LOGGER.info("configuring SSL engine for the server side of the connection with required client authorization");
    } else {
      LOGGER.info("configuring SSL engine for the server side of the connection without required client authorization");
    }
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
    sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(needClientAuth);
 }
  synchronized (ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES_LOCK) {
    if (enabledCipherSuites == null) {
      iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384");
      iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
      iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA");
      iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");

      // TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is the negotiated cipher suite for iOS

      // select and arrange the highest security cipher suites and cache the result
      final String[] supportedCipherSuites = sslEngine.getSupportedCipherSuites();
      final List<String> enabledCipherSuitesList = new ArrayList<>(supportedCipherSuites.length);
      // The first pass selects 256 bit ciphers available with the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)
      // Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files, downloaded and installed from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp .
      for (final String supportedCipherSuite : supportedCipherSuites) {
        if (supportedCipherSuite.contains("_256_") && !supportedCipherSuite.contains("_anon_")) {
          enabledCipherSuitesList.add(supportedCipherSuite);
        }
      }
      // The second pass selects 128 bit ciphers that use SHA hashing - its more secure than MD5 but slower.
      for (final String supportedCipherSuite : supportedCipherSuites) {
        if (supportedCipherSuite.contains("_128_") && !supportedCipherSuite.endsWith("_MD5") && !supportedCipherSuite.contains("_anon_")) {
          enabledCipherSuitesList.add(supportedCipherSuite);
        }
      }
      // The third pass selects 128 bit ciphers that use MD5 hashing.
      for (final String supportedCipherSuite : supportedCipherSuites) {
        if (supportedCipherSuite.contains("_128_") && supportedCipherSuite.endsWith("_MD5") && !supportedCipherSuite.contains("_anon_")) {
          enabledCipherSuitesList.add(supportedCipherSuite);
       }
      }
      // The fourth pass removes the iOS incompatible cipher suites
      enabledCipherSuitesList.removeAll(iOSIncompatibleCipherSuites);

      if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("enabledCipherSuites: " + enabledCipherSuitesList);
      }
      final int enabledCipherSuitesList_size = enabledCipherSuitesList.size();
      enabledCipherSuites = new String[enabledCipherSuitesList_size];
      for (int i = 0; i < enabledCipherSuitesList_size; i++) {
        enabledCipherSuites[i] = enabledCipherSuitesList.get(i);
      }
    }
    sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);
  }
}
```